# how to Post Array of jsonObject with urlencoded mime type in android?

Tags: android, json, mime-types

I am trying to call post API `content type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  an array of Json object on android

```
key1:[{key: value}, {key: value}]
key2:["id","id1","id3"]
```

getting error

Comment: please, improve the text on your question, it´s difficult to understand what is exactly your problem. Please, try pasting your piece of code, and read carefully the help section -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What kind of error is that? Which library are you using? Please [edit] your question to include that information.